# Is there a way in Golang to set flags when trying to execute `go test ./... -v`

Tags: go, arguments, command

I need to execute something like `go test ./... -v -args -name1 val1`
But nothing that works with `go test ...` seems to work with `go test ./...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go test framework uses the global [`flag.(*FlagSet)`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#FlagSet) instance. Any flags created in test files are available from the commands line. Positional arguments that aren't consumed by the test framework are available via [`flag.Args()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Args) (and `flag.Arg`, `flag.NArg`). Positional args will need `--` to separate them on the command line.

For example:

```golang
package testflag

import (
    "flag"
    "testing"
)

var value = flag.String("value", "", "Test value to log")

func TestFlagLog(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("Value = %q", *value)
    t.Logf("Args = %q", flag.Args())
}
```

Assuming the above test is in several directories `testflag`, `testflag/a`, and `testflag/b`, running `go test -v ./... -value bar -- some thing` outputs:

```
=== RUN   TestFlagLog
    testflag_test.go:11: Value = "bar"
    testflag_test.go:12: Args = ["some" "thing"]
--- PASS: TestFlagLog (0.00s)
PASS
ok          testflag        0.002s
=== RUN   TestFlagLog
    testflag_test.go:11: Value = "bar"
    testflag_test.go:12: Args = ["some" "thing"]
--- PASS: TestFlagLog (0.00s)
PASS
ok          testflag/a      0.001s
=== RUN   TestFlagLog
    testflag_test.go:11: Value = "bar"
    testflag_test.go:12: Args = ["some" "thing"]
--- PASS: TestFlagLog (0.00s)
PASS
ok          testflag/b      0.002s
```